# Merge different values from a jquery modal form and present this values in a drop down list

Tags: php, jquery

I am quite new to web design programming. I am using the jqueryui modal form to create a form that allows a user set up a meeting by entering the names and other details for a visitor. If this user wants to add more visitors, there is a button on the form that opens another smaller jquery modal form so as to add the new visitor's first name and surname(for the same meeting).

What I want to know is how i can merge the first name and surname created on both forms to form a drop down list so that the user can view the first name and surname of all the visitors attending the meeting.

(I don't want to load the values from a database, i want it to reflect right away before saving it to a database).

Here is a sample.

```
    $( "#dialog-form" ).dialog({
  autoOpen: false,
  modal: true,
  buttons: {
    "Create Meeting": function() {
      var bValid = true;
      allFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );
if ( bValid ) {
        $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<tr>" +
          "<td>" + meetname.val() + "</td>" +
     "<td>" + "<select>" + "<option>"+ firstname.val() + "&nbsp;" + surname.val()+  "</option>" + "</select>" + "</td>" + "</tr>");

      }
    },
"Add More Visitors": function() {
        $( "#another-dialog-modal" ).dialog('open');
    },

$("#dialogSelect").change(function(){
$( "#another-dialog-modal" ).dialog('open');});
$( "#another-dialog-modal" ).dialog({
autoOpen: false,
modal: true,
buttons: {
    Cancel: function() {
        $(this).dialog('close');
    },
"Add Visitor": function() {
var bValid = true;
      notallFields.removeClass( "ui-state-error" );

if ( bValid ) {
        $( "#users tbody" ).append( "<select>" + "<option>"+ fn.val() + "&nbsp;" + sn.val() + "</option>" + "</select>" );
        $( this ).dialog( "close" );
      }
    }
```

What I want is how to combine the values from the first select tag and the second select tag. So it can be displayed on the html page as one drop down list.

I hope the question is clear?

Comment: Could you provide a code sample that illustrate your problem.

Comment: Thanks for your response, I have added a sample of the code I'm working with. What do you think of it

Comment: If you're still having issues I'd love to help you out... could you possibly go to http://jsfiddle.net/ and create a demo of your issue.